# Deleting appended divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form with an input field and a button. I want on button click to append divs in my `list` div, with the content from the input field. Then, I want to remove each of these divs whenever I click on them.

I made a script that adds them on button click, and should delete them on clicking the div.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#button').click(function () {
        var toAdd = $('input[name=checkListItem]').val();
        $('.list').append('<div class="item">' + toAdd +
            '</div>');

    });

    $('.item').click(function () {
        $(this).remove();
    });


});
```

```css
h2 {
    font-family:arial;
}
form {
    display: inline-block;
}
#button {
    display: inline-block;
    height:20px;
    width:70px;
    background-color:#cc0000;
    font-family:arial;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#ffffff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:2px;
}
.list {
    font-family:garamond;
    color:#cc0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>To Do</h2>

<form name="checkListForm">
    <input type="text" name="checkListItem" />
</form>
<div id="button">Add!</div>
<br/>
<div class="list"></div>
```

The divs are added upon clicking the button, but on clicking them nothing happens. They should be removed.

Why do the appended `divs` don't get deleted when I click on them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the click is only attaching to dom elements when its call, you should do something like

```
$('body').on('click', '.item', function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Because they aren't in the DOM when you select the elements to add the event listener to. Try this instead.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/YTDsX/)

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button').click(function(){
        var toAdd = $('input[name=checkListItem]').val();
        $('<div class="item">' + toAdd + '</div>').click(function() {
            $(this).remove();
        }).appendTo('.list');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The $('.item') selector you use doesn't match (initially) any tag so it doesn't do anything. You need to use .on to ask jquery to match future tags. See http://jsfiddle.net/db8jX/2/

```
    $(document).on('click', '.item', function() {
       $(this).remove();
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

This question has already been answered by others, but here is another solution you could use to get the appended `div`s to disappear on click:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button').click(function(){
        var toAdd = $('input[name=checkListItem]').val();
        $('.list').append('<div class="item" onclick="$(this).remove()">' + toAdd + '</div>');
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/db8jX/3/)